# Exception on setting ViewPagerAdapter that extends FragmentPagerAdapter in viewPager in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a drawer layout and tab layout on the same activity. After adding adding navigation drawer the app was running fine but after adding tab layout code to my app the app is getting crashed throwing null pointer exception which i am not able to understand. Below is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
package kbg.com.kbgpos;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hamburgerColor));
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        tabLayout=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Personal_Info_Fragment(),"Personal Info");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new EducationalExperience_Info_Fragment(),"Educational_Exp Info");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new OtherInfo_Fragment(),"Other Info");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"></include>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/viewPager">

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#006699"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
package kbg.com.kbgpos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles=new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments,String titles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
08-15 22:10:26.389 31693-31693/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kbg.com.kbgpos, PID: 31693
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kbg.com.kbgpos/kbg.com.kbgpos.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at kbg.com.kbgpos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Please help i am novice in this field and have checked many links but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this line in your xml file:

```
viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

To this id:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It means a lot. Could you please let me know the reason as i am getiing blue colored full screens on main activity thought the code is running fine.